# Display Azure Service Principal Rights

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We have a Azure setup with multiple subscriptions, right now we would like to review the access rights of certain service principals. We were wondering whether there is a way to visualize all the access rights of a service principal? (E\either through the Azure Portal, `az cli` or PowerShell)?

I can't seem to find a streamlined way - It may be the case I am overlooking something :-)

Comment: Do you have a chance to look into my answer? Is it helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Get-AzRoleAssignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azroleassignment?view=azps-3.4.0) to list the roles of a service principal.

For example: `Get-AzRoleAssignment -ServicePrincipalName "http://testapp1.com"`.

See reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/create-azure-service-principal-azureps?view=azps-3.4.0#manage-service-principal-roles).

For Azure CLI reference, see [Manage service principal roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli?toc=%2Fazure%2Fazure-resource-manager%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-cli-latest#manage-service-principal-roles).